# How to append data to a parsed XML object - Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

I am trying to take an xml document parsed with `lxml` `objectify` in python and add subelements to it.

The problem is that I can't work out how to do this. The only real option I've found is a complete reconstruction of the data with `objectify.Element` and `objectify.SubElement`, but that... doesn't make any sense.

With JSON for instance, I can just import the data as an object and navigate to any section and read, add and edit data super easily.

How do I parse an xml document with `objectify` so that I can add subelement data to it?

`data.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
  <items>
    <item> text_1 </item>
    <item> text_2 </item>
  </items>
</data>
```

I'm sure there is an answer on how to do this online but my search terminology is either bad or im dumb, but I can't find a solution to this question. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Unclear. What exactly have you tried? What is it that doesn't make sense?

Comment: To distill it into a single line: how do I parse an xml document and **add** stuff to it. Sorry about it very simple but I can't find an answer to it.

Comment: Specifically, what `function` i can use to actually add to it.  My understanding is that functions like `objectify.Element`  and `objectify.SubElement` can only be used to `construct` xml datasets and not `append` to existing datasets. Like, I literally dont understand how you can append data to a parsed dataset. Does that sort of make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it has been quite difficult explain the question, but the problem can essentially be defined by an ambiguity with how `.Element` and `.SubElement` can be applied.

[This reference](https://youtu.be/bWfAD7wAfOI?t=1778) contains actionable and replicable ways in which one can `append` or `add` data to a parsed XML file.

Solving the key problem of:

**How do I reference content in a nested tag without reconstructing the entire tree?**

The author uses the **find feature**, which is called with `root.findall(./tag)`

This allows one to find the `nested tag` that they wanted without having to reconstruct the tree.

---

Here is one of the examples that they have used:

```py
cost = ["$2000","$3000","$4000")
traveltime = ["3hrs", "8hrs", "15hrs"]
i = 0

for elm in root.findall("./country"):
    ET.SubElement(elm, "Holiday", attrib={"fight_cost": cost[i],
                                          "trip_duration": traveltime[i]})
    i += 1
```

This example also answers the question of **How do you dynamically add data to XML?**

They have accomplished this by using a list outside of the loop and ieteration through it with `i`

In essence, this example helps explain how to reference nested content without remaking the entire tree, as well as how to dynamically add data to xml trees.